# How do I highlight the active menu using javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use the script below to highlight the active menu in twitter bootstrap.

```
/* This is cool it sets the right navbar element active */
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

The bootstrap html the above script works on looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href="/about/">About</a></li>
    <li> <a href="/articles/">Articles</a></li>

</ul>
```

If the url is, say:

```
example.com/articles/
```

It works great and the articles menu item is highlighted

However, if the url is say:

```
example.com/articles/cars
example.com/articles/cars/
example.com/articles/cars/mini
```

It no longer sets the articles menu item active.

Any ideas how I can get it to set the menu item active for child articles too?

** UPDATE **

I'm currently on a dev box and my URL looks like this:

```
http://192.168.0.100:8001/about/
http://192.168.0.100:8001/articles/
http://192.168.0.100:8001/articles/cars/
```

Comment: just use "^=" selector :) 'a[href^="' + this.location.pathname + '"]'

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. Thanks anyway.